# get rid of the end of lines matching pattern linux

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to get list of ip addresses from configuration, and I receive them in format: `*.*.*.*:*` where the last field is the port number of the established connection.
how can I get rid of the port numeber?
here is the line i do now:

```
ss -ta | tail -n +2 |awk  '{print $4}' | sort -u
```

I understand I need using sed as pipe between awk and sort for removing the part after the colon, but I am not sure how to do it the right way.

the line `ss -ta`
returns the following:

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port                 Peer Address:Port                
LISTEN     0      128            *:ssh                          *:*                    
LISTEN     0      100    127.0.0.1:smtp                         *:*                    
CLOSE-WAIT 32     0      192.168.1.7:48474                104.18.35.72:https                
CLOSE-WAIT 32     0      192.168.1.7:52879                104.18.34.72:https                
CLOSE-WAIT 1      0      192.168.1.7:38492                82.80.211.109:http                 
LISTEN     0      128           :::ssh                         :::*                    
LISTEN     0      100          ::1:smtp                        :::*                    
ESTAB      0      52     fe80::a00:27ff:fead:6df2%enp0s3:ssh               fe80::e1
```

this is the output to my command:

```
> 127.0.0.1:smtp

> 192.168.1.7:38492

> 192.168.1.7:48474

> 192.168.1.7:52879

>  ::1:smtp 

> fe80::a00:27ff:fead:6df2%enp0s3:ssh

> :::ssh

> *:ssh
```

the desired output is:

```
> 127.0.0.1

> 192.168.1.7
```

thanks

Comment: Provide a corpus, and your desired output.

Answer (score 4):

Without testable sample input and expected output it's a bit of a guess but it sounds like all you need is

```
ss -ta | awk '{$0=$4;sub(/:[^:]+$/,"")} NR>1 && !seen[$0]++'
```

e.g. using `cat file` instead of `ss ta` to pipe your expected input to the command:

```
$ cat file | awk '{$0=$4;sub(/:[^:]+$/,"")} NR>1 && !seen[$0]++'
*
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.7
::
::1
fe80::a00:27ff:fead:6df2%enp0s3
```

but if we look at your posted expected output then maybe what you really want is more like:

```
$ cat file | awk '{$0=$4;sub(/:[^:]+$/,"")} NR>1 && /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}/ && !seen[$0]++'
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the port removal with gnu awk, use `awk  '{print gensub(/:.*/,"","g",$4)}'` in your original pipe.

Comment: ++, but perhaps replace `"g"` with `1` for clarity.

Comment: and mention it's gawk (and mawk?) specific due to gensub() and change the regexp to `:[^:]*$` to remove from the last `:` to the end instead of from the first.

Answer (score 0):

just use the regex to delete everything after `:`, you can use:

```
ss -ta | tail -n +2 |awk  '{print $4}' | sort -u | sed 's/:.*$//g' | uniq
```

or you can even use `awk` with `:` as the field separator:

```
ss -ta | tail -n +2 |awk  '{print $4}' | sort -u | awk -F : '{print $1}' | uniq
```

or cut with delimeter as `:`

```
ss -ta | tail -n +2 |awk  '{print $4}' | sort -u | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq
```